# Hide specific sub-folders in Explorer Navigation Pane

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have found many variations of this question, but nothing quite like I want.

I want to hide various subfolders in the navigation pane - specifically the folders I have already hidden in my User Folder.

These folders - Saved Games, Searches, My Documents (which somehow became the dumping ground for every piece of software to store their crap), etc, are so astonishingly useless that I am tempted delete them outright, but I've learned things usually go awry somewhere down the line when I delete folders from certain places.   I never even enter these folders, so I for sure do not need them mucking up what could be a really useful way to get to folders I do use.

I could just drag everything I use into favorites, but that gets disorganized, and makes it harder to find the folders that really are my "Favorites".

**NOTE**:  I am aware of the possibility of hiding the entire USER folder.  I do not want this.  I use this folder for several things, and it contains folders that I access almost every time I open explorer.

Any joy here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide or Delete the User Home Folder in Windows Explorer Navigation Pane](http://superuser.com/questions/406663/hide-or-delete-the-user-home-folder-in-windows-explorer-navigation-pane)

Comment: @oliver-salzburg.  Please remove your edit.  This is quite clearly a different question.

Comment: @techie007: Same.

Comment: You should be careful with removing those folders. A lot of software makes use of them because they're considered "system folders" and are embedded in all nooks and cranks of your OS. Simply use your NTFS permissions to hide folders and don't display hidden folders in your view.

Comment: @Jakke:  This doesn't work.  The attributes are set to hidden, and hidden folders are set not to be shown in explorer folder properties.  They are displayed anyway.  Also, please read the question fully before answering - this is all indicated in the post.